# How to change the author of the sidebar of hexo(next theme)?

Tags: html, hexo

I've changed the author in the configuration file, but I only get my name changed at the bottom of the website, while the name of the sidebar remains unchanged(following is the unchanged sidebar, and another figure of my name changed at the bottom of the website):

[image]
[image]

So, since I've changed the *author* setting in my configuration, how can I make this also be used in the name of my sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two configurations, one for hexo, one for next theme. I changed the one in *next* theme while forgetting the one in hexo configuration.